# Regex for Empty String or 10 digits

Tags: c#, regex

To start: I've just started with Regexes, and I've had a *really* difficult time understanding what's going on with them.  Just a heads-up.

For a project, I'm trying to develop a regex that takes either A) an empty string (in C# speak, ""), or B) ten (10) digits.  I've been able to figure out how to accomplish the 10-digits part:

```
"^[0-9X]{10}$"
```

...But not the 'empty string or' part.  which I imagine would be something like:

```
"^[]$|^[0-9X]{10}$"
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but I have no idea how to write something that *does*, even though there are quite a few topics on the matter.

Questions:

A) What is a regex that will return true if the given string is either a string.Empty (rather, ""), or exactly 10 digits?

B) Please explain how exactly it works.  It's not that I haven't been trying to learn (I did figure out that the `^$` are anchors for exact-string matching, and that `|` is the OR operator...), it's just that regexes apparently do not come naturally to me...yet, I'm in a situation I must use them.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
(^$)|(^\d{10}$)
```

The first option matches the empty string, the second option matches 10 digits.

I don't know what your X is for, unless you're looking for a hex string, if that is the case, you'll want to do the following:

```
(^$)|(^[0-9a-fA-FxX]{10}$)
```

Comment: Didn't know what the X stood for - I thought it was some variable-length attribute like [charactersX]{quantity} - thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 3):

```
^$|^[0-9X]{10}$
```

`^` means match the start, `$` means match the end as there is nothing in between, match nothing. If there is something, this doesn't match

`|` is the alternation operator, between alternatives

Comment: Oh btw, dunno why you've got an X in your character class?  Maybe you need to match "19X56"?

Comment: Seems like OP wishes to match hexadecimal numbers as well? i.e. `0x123abc`

Comment: Not after hexadecimal numbers, originally copied an example that had the [0-9X] component.  This involves US Phone Numbers...was curious about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 string a = "0123456789";
 string b = "";
 string reg = @"^(|\d{10})$";

 if ( Regex.IsMatch( a, reg ) && Regex.IsMatch( b, reg ) ) {
     Console.WriteLine( "Matched" );
 }
```

`\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`
`{10}` is ten times exactly
`|` is the OR operator
`^` is the start, `$` is the end
The brackets limit the OR operation to nothing or ten digits between the start and end.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below REGEX ... it will work...

```
        if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^(?!\s*$).+")) //Check Not Empty String 
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^\d{10}$")) // Check ten digits - Not allowed Alphanumeric
            {
                MessageBox.Show("find Ten digits");
            }
            else
            {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty String Found");
        }
```